# Saving to multiple hidden fields in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using ASP.net MVC. I have three jquery sliders in the view

```
<div class="slider" data-hiddenfield="amount" style="width:200px;"></div>
```

and accompanying hidden html fields whose value will save to db.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.fear, new { @id = "cvar" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.control, new { @id = "cvar" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.danger, new { @id = "dvar" })
```

Is it possible to use the same Javascript code and save the value of the slider dynamically to all three hidden fields, before form submission?

Slider Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$(function () {
    $(".slider").slider({
        orientation: "Horizontal",
        range: "min",
        min: 0,
        max: 100,
        value: 60,
        slide: function (event, ui) {
            $("#cvar").val(ui.value); //to be saved to hidden field
            var g = parseInt(ui.value <= 50 ? 255 : 255 - ((ui.value - 50) * (255 / 50)));
            var r = parseInt(ui.value >= 50 ? 255 : 255 - ((50 - ui.value) * (255 / 50)));
            $(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "rgb(" + r + "," + g + ",0)");
        },

        create: function (event, ui) {
            $(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "rgb(255, 200 ,0)");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: You only need one document.ready handler; you can safely remove `$(document).ready(function () {`

Comment: Noted. One last thing, since the user might choose to leave the slider at its default value, is there a simpler way apart from using startPos and endPos and calculating the difference at the end?

Comment: The simplest way would be to default the value of the hidden fields to match the sliders, in this case `60`.

Comment: Just arranged it - works :) thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you should give your hidden inputs a unique class as duplicate `id` attributes in a single document is invalid. You can then amend the `data-hiddenfield` attribute on the slider to match the id of the related input:

```
<div class="slider" data-hiddenfield="fear" style="width:200px;"></div>
<div class="slider" data-hiddenfield="control" style="width:200px;"></div>
<div class="slider" data-hiddenfield="danger" style="width:200px;"></div>
```

```csharp
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.fear, new { @id = "fear" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.control, new { @id = "control" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.danger, new { @id = "danger" })
```

Then in the slider `slide` handler you can read the hidden field property and set the value of the appropriate input, like this:

```
slide: function (event, ui) {
    $('#' + $(event.target).data('hiddenfield')).val(ui.value);
    var g = parseInt(ui.value <= 50 ? 255 : 255 - ((ui.value - 50) * (255 / 50)));
    var r = parseInt(ui.value >= 50 ? 255 : 255 - ((50 - ui.value) * (255 / 50)));
    $(event.target).find(".ui-widget-header").css("background", "rgb(" + r + "," + g + ",0)");
},
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/a40w0ysd/)

In the example I used visible text fields to make the effect obvious, it will still work absolutely fine with hidden inputs.

Also note the use of `find()` from the event target to fix the issue of all bar colours being changed instead of the one which is being amended.

Comment: This also creates a situation where the colour of all three sliders changes - any ideas of how the colour can remain slider-specific, and hence retain individual shade?

Comment: No problem, glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

First, do not give the same id value to all your input fields. Id's should be unique for elements. No two elements should have the same Id value.`Html.HiddenFor` helper method will generate an `Id` and `name` for your input field from the model/property meta information.

Give same  a css class name for all the hidden fields.

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.fear, new { @class= "myClass" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.control, new { @class= "myClass" })
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.danger, new {  @class= "myClass" })
```

Now in your javascript you can use the css class as the jQuery selector and set the value.

```
$(".myClass").val(ui.value);
```